# Convergence in $L^p$ of an approximation to a function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lp-spaces

Suppose you have a function $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and some bounded set $\Omega$ of measure 1. Define
$$ f_\epsilon = \frac1{\epsilon^n}\int_{\Omega_\epsilon} f(x + y)dy $$
Where $\Omega_\epsilon$ is the set $\{y:y/\epsilon\in\Omega\}$. My problem is to prove that $f_\epsilon\to f$ in $L^p$.

It has been several years since I've taken an analysis class and I recall solving problems like this without too much trouble, but it seems like I've forgotten something crucial. I've tried various applications of Jensen's Inequality, Holder's inequality, Fubini's Theorem, rewriting $f_\epsilon$ as a convolution, and clicking through related topics on Wikipedia, but nothing I do seems to be leading toward a solution.

This isn't homework, it came from an old analysis final at my school.

I hope this is not a duplicate, it is a very TeX-y question and difficult to search for. Apologies if it is completely trivial.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\tau_h$ denote the translation operator, given by $\tau_h f(x) = f(x+h)$. Now, for $1 \leqslant p < \infty$, we know that $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and it is easy to see that for $f \in C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ we have $\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \lVert \tau_hf - f\rVert_p = 0$. Since the $\tau_h$ are isometries, the family $\{\tau_h : h \in \mathbb{R}^n\}$ is an equicontinuous family of operators $L^p \to L^p$, hence we have $\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \lVert \tau_h f - f\rVert_p = 0$ for all $f \in L^p$ (even uniformly on all compact subsets of $L^p$, but we don't need that).

Now, we can also write (by a change of variables $y' = \varepsilon y$ in the definition of $f_\varepsilon$)

$$f_\varepsilon(x) = \int_\Omega f(x+\varepsilon y) \, dy,$$

and then we can estimate $\lVert f_\varepsilon - f\rVert_p$ by an average of $\lVert \tau_hf -f\rVert_p$:

$$\begin{align}
\lVert f_\varepsilon - f\rVert_p^p &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left \lvert \int_\Omega f(x+\varepsilon y) - f(x)\, dy \right\rvert^p\,dx \quad \text{(Jensen)}\\
&\leqslant \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_\Omega \lvert f(x+\varepsilon y) - f(x)\rvert^p \,dy\,dx \quad \text{(Fubini)}\\
&= \int_\Omega \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \lvert f(x+\varepsilon y) - f(x)\rvert^p\,dx\,dy\\
&= \int_\Omega \lVert \tau_{\varepsilon y}f - f\rVert_p^p\,dy.
\end{align}$$

Since $\Omega$ is bounded, by the above continuity property of the translations, for every $\delta > 0$ we can find an $\eta > 0$ such that for all $0 < \varepsilon < \eta$ and all $y \in \Omega$ we have $\lVert \tau_{\varepsilon y}f - f\rVert_p < \delta$, and that implies

$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \lVert f_\varepsilon -f \rVert_p = 0.$$

For $p = \infty$, the assertion does not hold.

Comment: Thanks very much! That I could extend equicontinuous families from $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ was exactly the missing piece.

Comment: On second thought, I'm not sure that $f\mapsto f_\epsilon$ is an isometry, so this solution for pure translations does not map wholesale to the original problem. However, it is not hard to show that $\|f_\epsilon\|_p\to 0$ as $\|f\|_p\to 0$ regardless of $f$ or $\epsilon$, and that $f\mapsto f_\epsilon$ is linear, and those are enough to make the jump from continuous compactly supported functions to all of $L^p$.

Comment: @AndrewPoelstra $f \mapsto f_\varepsilon$ is in general not an isometry. The proof nowhere supposed that. The $\tau_h$ are isometries. And by changing the order of integration, we estimate the distance between $f_\varepsilon$ and $f$ by an average of distances between $\tau_hf$ and $f$.

Comment: @DanielFischer You're right, my bad. I read "we can also write" and thought you were doing another (more explicit) proof that $\tau_{ey}$ is continuous in $L^p$, rather than attacking $f\mapsto f_\epsilon$.

Comment: @AndrewPoelstra Ah, I see. Just a change of variables in the definition of $f_\varepsilon$ to get a form that is nicer to handle (needs fewer $\varepsilon$s written).